# Xamarin Forms with Prism and DryIoc with a lot of registered page, can reduce performance?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

For example, we have a big Xamarin forms project, with 2000 page, and Prism MVVM framework, with DryIoc container, that has registered all 2000 pages.

This a lot of pages, added with DependencyService for example, navigationservice, dialogservice, can reduce navigation's speed and/or performance?
It can makes app run slow, for a lot of dependency?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple answer to this. The general one is - yes. The DryIoc, like any package, is an additional overhead to your project. The IoC container surely adds some time to the overall feeling. Keep in mind that the overhead is minimal - in the matter of some milliseconds. Like it says in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc):

> Designed for low-ceremony use, performance, and extensibility.

DryIoc is considered to be a relatively fast container. Here is the official [IoC Container Benchmark - Performance comparison](https://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison).

But again, it all depends on how many services you need to instantiate. It doesn't matter if you have 2000 pages. It matters how many dependencies you will have with these pages and how many [circular dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) also.

Also, some of the IoC logic is being done on app start-up and you can also match some of the resolving there.

To sum up - it is better to have IoC container, than to not have one because the flexibility, that you get from it, beats the eventual small overhead of performance.

Comment: Thank for answer, but the worst case, can ioc and dependency service, there may be a slowdown detectable by the user, who uses the app?

Comment: Well, of course that there may be. Every package that you add adds to the total overhead to the user. The idea here is what the worst case will be - is it 50 pages each with 1-2 dependencies, or 3000 pages each with 10+ dependencies. Overall, the answer should be no. If you have 3000 pages with 10+ dependencies each, the DryIoc will be the least problematic for your performance.